# How to lock file without creating temp files?

Tags: python

I try to use python lockfile module, but this module create temprorary file to locking. If script was interrupt ( server reboot for example ), this temp file not deleted and file remains locked.

Comment: Place the lockfile in `/tmp`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fcntl module

```
import fcntl
fcntl.flock('myfile', fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
```

the second parameter here are flags which define in which way you want to lock the file, see [The doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.flock)

I'm not sure this works on non Unix-like systems